# list function in couch db getting a expression does not evaluate to a function error

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am a newbie to couchdb I copied and pasted a simple list function from couchdb wiki and i am
getting a expression does not evaluate to function error in my browser this is my code in couch I included the whole document

```
    {
   "_id": "_design/recipies",
   "_rev": "44-58a0833eb8834e801ca23f6fc82c2a6a",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "cup": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n\tif(doc.ingredients){\n\t\tfor (ingredient in doc.ingredients){\n\t\t\tif(doc.ingredients[ingredient].cup){\n\t\t\t\tvalue = ingredient;\n\t\t\t\tkey = doc.ingredients[ingredient].cup;\nemit(key, value);}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n\n\n  \n}"
       }
   },
   "lists": {
       "index-posts": "function(doc, req) {provides('html', function() {var html = '<html><body><ol>\n'; while (row === getRow()) { html += '<li>' + row.key + ':' + row.value + '</li>\n';} html += '</ol></body></head>';return html;});}"
   }
}
```

This is the error i am getting in my browser

```
{"error":"compilation_error","reason":"Expression does not eval to a function. (function(doc, req) {provides('html', function() {var html = '<html><body><ol>\n'; while (row === getRow()) { html += '<li>' + row.key + ':' + row.value + '</li>\n';} html += '</ol></body></head>';return html;});})"}
```

I would like to know what is wrong with the function thanks

Comment: Please add some more detail, you should include any error messages and ask a specific question.

Comment: thanks for your comment i included the error message and hopefully clarified the question thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to call:

```
while (row = getRow()){
```

instead of:

```
while (row === getRow()){
```

And your newline characters within quoted strings need to be escaped:

```
'<li>' + row.key + ':' + row.value + '</li>\\n'
```

Comment: thanks so much works i am new to stackoverflow is there a way for me to give a upvote or something